# Boost if array in field contains a certain object which matches a string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which look like this:

```
{
   "names": [
      {
         "type": "Main Name",
         "value": "My important title"
      },
      {
         "type": "Subtitle",
         "value": "Just my subtitle"
      }
   ],
}
```

What I want to be able to do is pass a string and it be able to boost documents more where the string passed is contained in value of the item with the `type` `Main Name`. For example, searching for "important" will mean that the example document will score higher than if you search for "just" or "subtitle".

So far, I have the following sub-query(part of a larger query):

```
{
   "match_phrase": {
      "names.value": {
         "query": "important",
         "slop":  100
   }
}
```

But I don't really know how to distinguish between the fields in the array. I would want to do something like, if the `type` is "Main Name" and the `value` contains "important" then boost by 5. I have played around with the [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) keyword.

Is this possible?

#### - EDIT

After the comment, I have be able to build the following query which seems to work. Here is the query I am using in it's entirety:

```
{  
   "nested":{  
      "path":"propertyNames",
      "boost":1000,
      "query":{  
         "bool":{  
            "must":[  
               {  
                  "match":{  
                     "propertyNames.type.raw":{  
                        "query":"Primary Name"
                     }
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "match_phrase":{  
                     "propertyNames.value.raw":{  
                        "query":"downing"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The part that I am adding is the second nested query in `query.function_score.query.bool.should`. The data in propertyNames looks like this:

```
{
   "names": [
      {
         "type": "Primary Name",
         "value": "10 Downing Street"
      },
      {
         "type": "Other Name",
         "value": "The prime minister's house"
      }
   ],
}
```

If, the search term was "downing", then the above document should get a higher score. If it was "prime", then it shouldn't be boosted.

However, the part that I have added is making no difference whatsoever.

I think that this is roughly correct. I have been playing around with lots of combinations of the `should`s and `must`s but no combination gives the correct results.

Am I along the right lines here?

It doesn't matter if the nested query that I have added is there or not. The same results are returned.

Comment: you need to use a nested query for that and thus to specify in your mapping that names is a nested property. See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html . The nested type will ensure elastic handle your "names" in a document as a collection and their properties will not be flattened (it will be bright clear after reading the link content)

Comment: @PierreMallet Have I done what you mean? Any chance you know about my issue in the edit?

Comment: Could you try to simplify your non-working example? It's hard to help you this way. Just use some nested properties and try to make a boost if the value is X and the type Y like you did in the original question? Just post your simple query and I will try to find time to reproduce by myself.

Comment: @PierreMallet Sorry, I have simplified my query.

Comment: ok, ill try to reproduce tomorrow and get you a working example

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working example with the nested type.

Here is the mapping with the nested type to keep track of relation between a names value and his type.

```
PUT test_stack_overflow
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "names": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some document for the test

```
PUT test_stack_overflow/document/1
{
  "names": [
      {
         "type": "Primary Name",
         "value": "10 downing Street"
      },
      {
         "type": "Other Name",
         "value": "The something minister's house"
      }
   ]
}

PUT test_stack_overflow/document/2
{
  "names": [
      {
         "type": "Primary Name",
         "value": "10 something Street"
      },
      {
         "type": "Other Name",
         "value": "The downing house"
      }
   ]
}
```

And an example of a way ( there a lot a way of achieving what you are aiming for ) to boost matches of `Primary Name` type.

We use a boolean query that specifies that we need to find the query in any `names.value` and that a matching document should find this value in a `names` with the type `Primary Name` ( the should clause will add a score boost if the condition is met )

```
GET test_stack_overflow/document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "names",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "names.value": "downing"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

=> returns the two documents with the exact same score

```
GET test_stack_overflow/document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "names",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "names.value": "downing"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "names.type": "Primary Name"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

=> returns document 1 first

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Hi Pierre, this doesn't seem to fit what I wanted. This seems to say, there must be a value called "downing" and there should be a "Primary Name". I want to boost a document's score if there is an object in the names array with the type of "Primary Name" and the value in the same object contains "downing". Have I misunderstood your query?

Comment: And thats exactly what this query does. If you remove the should clause, then the two document will be matched with the same score. If you add the should clauses, then the document where the string match in the object with type of "Primary name" will have a higher score.

Comment: i just corrected some error in the queries results description. But you should run them on your own to check the results

Comment: That's perfect! I have it working now! Thank you very much.